# How to read correctly the image from S3 in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, amazon-s3

I am using Ubuntu and Firefox. I want to see an image from a bucket Amazon S3, but when I double-click on it a new tab is opening (that is normal), but I cannot see the jpeg. I see just:

```
�����JFIF���������C�      





   


���C
```

or something similar.

I have also installed the [S3Fox](http://www.s3fox.net/), but this seems that has not fixed the problem.

I have installed Google Chrome, and it seems that it shows it correctly (so it is not a problem of authentication); but I do not like the Chrome browser...

Is there another way to make this accessible in Firefox?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall firefox?

Comment: I have just reinstall firefox, following the steps [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed), but I get the same result of decoding. To me it is something like decoding the jpg

Comment: What image? What is the URL? This may depend entirely on how Amazon serves the content. We cannot simply guess at what is going on...

Comment: I cannot post the URL, it's a private bucket... Why does it works fine in Chrome and in Firefox it shows me that? In fact I had some images that were available in Firefox too, but they are on another bucket. I have compared the URLs and the only thing that differs are the signature, the buckets names and the images names and the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comment I have another bucket and I can see the images from that one (at least some of them, that I have tested). The only difference between the urls of the images are the bucket name, the image name, the signature and the date.

I have started to compare the properties of the images:
 * the permissions are the same
 * the details are the same
 * but the metadata differs: `text/plain; charset=utf-8` and `image/jpeg`

It seems that this is the problem: I save the image on the bucket as plain text, I think...

But why doesn't Firefox read it correctly, as Chrome?